# Laravel eloquent using null as column value on select?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

How to use null as column value in the Laravel eloquent like in the following query (The below query is not working and its for an example).

```
$query = \DB::table('invoices as inv')
        ->leftjoin('customer as c', 'c.id', '=', 'inv.customer_id')
        ->select([
            'inv.id',
            'inv.invoice_date',
            'inv.invoice_no',
            'null as voucher_no',
            'null as credit',
        ]);
```

Here, '**null as voucher_no**' is not working. How to use null inside this query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`DB::raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions) around your columns, which will force laravel to pass the column name as is:

```
$query = \DB::table('invoices as inv')
    ->leftjoin('customer as c', 'c.id', '=', 'inv.customer_id')
    ->select([
        'inv.id',
        'inv.invoice_date',
        'inv.invoice_no',
        DB::raw('null as voucher_no'),
        DB::raw('null as credit'),
    ]);
```